# Windows Service for mass Mailing

Tags: .net

Can Windows service be used for fetching data from DB and mailing(around 300 mails) giving a 15 minutes time interval with a timer?

Is Windows service a good option to use for this scenario.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the program amounts to:

```
while (true)
{
    SendEmailsFromDatabase();
    Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15));
}
```

Then you don't want a Windows service. You want a console application and a scheduled task. See [Programs are not cats](http://blog.mischel.com/2013/02/01/programs-are-not-cats/).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I am talking about a Web Application. I have a scenario for sending mass mailing every 15 minutes.Please suggest a good Option for this.

Comment: @G.R: A console application can access the Internet. If you need a Web frontend to collect information from users and stores it in a database, fine. But the piece that checks the database and sends emails shouldn't be a Web app. My suggestion stands: for sending mails, use a console app that's activated by a scheduled task.